# Issues with binary search tree

Tags: java, data-structures

I need some help to why an insertion in a bst doesn't work on the following code. Is there some concept on how java passes parameters that I do not know?

```
 public void insert(int input){
        insert(root, input);
}
private void insert(Node node, int input){
    Node new_node = new Node(input);
    if (node == null) {
        node = new_node;
        }
    else if (input == node.data) {
        System.out.println("input exists");
        }
    else {
        if (input < node.data) {
            insert(node.left, input);
        }
        else{
            insert(node.right, input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The parameter `Node node` is a local variable. Reassigning that won't have an effect. Java is call by value.

Comment: also you're assigning a value to null, it's like a floating node, not attached to anything.

Comment: Thank you @f1sh, This really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reassigning the parameter `node` won't change anything about the thing you passed to the method (`node.left` or `node.right`):

```
node = new_node;
```

Because `node` stores a reference to the `Node` object (that you want to replace). The assignment only changes the reference so that it refers to another object. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777269/when-can-and-cant-method-calls-change-a-parameter-in-java) for more info.

You could reassign `node.left` and `node.right` instead:

```
Node new_node = new Node(input);
if (input == node.data) {
    System.out.println("input exists");
} else if (input < node.data) {
    if (node.left != null) {
        insert(node.left, input);
    } else {
        node.left = new_node;
    }
}
else{
    if (node.right != null) {
        insert(node.right, input);
    } else {
        node.right = new_node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert like this in the BST

```
    public void insert(int val) {
        root = put(root, val);
    }

    private Node insert(Node node, int val) {
        if (node == null)
            return new Node(val);
        int cmp = Integer.valueOf(val).compareTo(node.data);
        if (cmp < 0)
            node.left = insert(node.left, val);
        else if (cmp > 0)
            node.right = insert(node.right, val);
        else
            node.data = val;
        return node;
    }
```